# Как установить библиотеку QtCrypto?

Tags: qt, c++, lib

Хочу использовать QtCrypto в моем проекте, а как подключить не знаю.
Скачал с сайта готовую скомпилируемую версию.
Переместил файлы в корневую папку проекта
В .pro файл добавил следующее:

```
LIBS += -L./qca/lib
INCLUDEPATH += qca/include/QtCrypto
CONFIG += crypto
```

В папку Qt5.2.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin добавил dll со скачанной папки \bin
Создал проект для теста в QCreator и добавил туда немного кода с примера.
Запустил qmake.
Собрал проект.
Как результат я получил ошибки линковщика. Почему?

Относительно кода, для тех кто скажет, что ошибки в нем, напишу следующее:
если убрать код, а кода было всего 1 строка, то все работает.

Может быть я что-то не так сделал?

Если кому не сложно, то установите у себя и дайте ваш pro файл. Спасибо большое.

Windows 7 x86. Visual 2012. Qt5

Скачал библиотеку с [оф. сайта](http://delta.affinix.com/qca/). Если прокрутить в самый низ, то там Visual Studio 2005

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Доброго времени суток!

Возможно Ваша проблема в том, что путь к библиотеке (*.lib) вы указали, а саму библиотеку - нет. Правильно использовать директиву LIB надо так:

```
LIB += -L<путь> -l<имя_библиотеки>
```

Обратите внимание, что перед именем библиотеки **должен стоять префикс** `-l` а **имя файла библиотеки указывается без расширения**!

Я сам не скачивал QtCrypto, но скорее всего Ваш *.pro файл должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
LIBS += -L./qca/lib -lQtCrypto
INCLUDEPATH += qca/include/QtCrypto
CONFIG += crypto
```

Comment: Тогда возможно, проблема в пути к файлу, попробуйте указать полный путь (и будет очень хорошо если Вы его обернете в двойные кавычки). Меня, если честно, напрягает точка перед собственно путем) Я обычно задаю либо относительный путь (относительно директории с проектом), либо добавляю в переменные окружения новую переменную и использую ее. Можно еще путь добавить в переменную PATH. Сам я очень много ковырялся с подключением доп.библиотек к Qt, обычно именно эти ошибки возникали. Вы кстати можете вывести тот путь который видит qmake - посмотрите как это делается в документации на qmake.

Comment: Хмм... Очень странно.. У меня наоборот: без -l  и -L вообще работать не хочет))) Ну да ладно, рад что у Вас получилось!)